# Extending <redirect:write> in xalan

Tags: xslt, xalan

In my project, I have used the  function which xaln provided. Now I need to write another function to fix the meta data of the file which is generated by . So the code just like below:

```
<redirect:write file="file.html">
<xsl:variable name="meta_fix" select="MetaFix:fix(string,string('file.html'))" /> //call the fix function which is an external java function.
```

However, what i really want is to extend the xalan redirect function and make a customize tag which will be processed just like the

```
<customize:write file="file.html" fixMeta="t" />
//or
<redirect:customize-write file="file.html" fixMeta="t" />
```

How can I extend the xalan write function and make the xalan understand my customize tag?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible to plug an Entity Resolver into Xalan which will be able to review and rewrite URIs, which might let you put your hint into the URI rather than a separate flag variable or attribute. Check the documentation on Apache.

Or I suppose you could try copying the logic of redirect: out of the guts of xalan and adapting apprpriately, then plugging it in as an extension element. I don't remember whether extensions would be able to access enough of xalan's guts to make that work, though, and persionally I wouldn't try it since you'd be making your stylesheets extremely nonportable.